# Включить кэширование для картинок с GET запросом

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, get, кэширование

Мои фото загружались без get запроса, то есть `https://site.ru/img.jpg`, а сейчас я поставил get который будет задавать ему ширину и высоту - `https://site.ru/img.jpg?w=100&h=200` и после этого фото перестали кэшироваться

> HTACCESS!!!

Вот мое кэширование фотографий:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
# Включаем кэширование изображений и флэш на месяц
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 4 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 43829 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM.

> the Expires header will not be added to content that does not come from a file on disk

(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)

То есть данный модуль проставляет кеширующие заголовки только для контента который напрямую читается с диска. В вашем случае контент генерируется на лету и соответсвенно кеширующие заголовки нужно проставлять уже тем инструментом который модифицирует картинки.

Если это php-скрипт, то вот статейка https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+cache-control+%D0%B2+php%3F как это сделать